# How to check if an HTML element has no user facing data (e.g. text or pictures) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a web application that removes certain elements from a webpage, so after it is done with the initial pass, I want to remove all divs that used to contain data that no longer do. So for example, after the initial pass, an element might look like this:

```
<div class = "some-random-class">
    <script> *script stuff* </script>
    <div class = "some-other-class"> 
        <p>  </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I want to be able to detect that the div with "some-random-class" no longer contains any text (or the text is only whitespace), pictures, nor video, and only contains elements that are used for formatting or spacing. [For example, this link shows two empty boxes in a webpage made up with only divs and scripts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9jaz.png)

Comment: `if(!elm.children[0] && !elm.textContent.trim()){ elm.remove(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. If it has class name "some-other-class" and is empty then it will be deleted. You can change `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');` to `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');` if you want all tags, or change it to any other tag. Also you can remove `elements[i].className == "some-other-class" &&` if you want to delete any element that is empty even without having that class name.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
if (elements[i].className == "some-other-class" && elements[i].innerText.replace(" ","") == "" && elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf('<img') < 0 && elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf('<video') < 0){
    elements[i].parentElement.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class = "some-random-class">
    <div class = "some-other-class"> 
        <p> a </p>
    </div>
     <div class = "some-other-class"> 
        <p> <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif"> </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "some-other-class"> 
        <p> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't this also delete elements that still have pictures or video? I don't want to do that.

Comment: Yeah but you can use innerHTML instead of innerText, that way it has to be without tags or text, or you could add more conditions in if(...)

Comment: Looks good except I don't care about all white space, so instead of .innerText.replace(" ",""), I used trim().

Comment: Ok, I'm glad it helped :)